# .txt file to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, web-scraping

I want to extract the columns of a .txt file and put them into a pandas DataFrame or csv. I also need to extract some information from the header of the .txt file  and add them as columns in the dataframe/csv.

Here is the link of the file http://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/askyfou/2017-01.txt

[Partial screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbYMM.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.!

Comment: SO is not a coding service, it shows what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import StringIO

f = StringIO.StringIO()
r = requests.get('http://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/askyfou/2017-01.txt').content
f.write(r)

f.seek(0)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in f.readlines()[10:41]:
    df = df.append(pd.Series(x.split()),ignore_index=True)

df.columns = ['DAY','MEAN TEMP','HIGH1','TIME1','LOW',
              'TIME2','MAX RH','MIN RH','RAIN',
              'AVG WIND SPEED','HIGH2','TIME3','DOM DIR']

print df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks doc for your reply.

I tried this code

### specify the columns width

col_specification =[(0, 4), (5, 9), (11, 15), (16, 23), (24, 28), (29, 36), (37, 44),(45, 49),
                   (51, 55), (58, 63), (64,69)]

### Read the data from the url

data = pd.read_fwf('http://meteosearch.meteo.gr/data/askyfou/2017-01.txt', colspecs=col_specification, header = 8, skipfooter = 2, skipinitialspace = True)

and it seems to work, although is isn't automated like yours.
I assume you use python 2, right?